# parse error, expecting `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM' error in activecollab model class

Tags: php, permissions, module, controller, activecollab

I'm working on activecollab custom module's permissions, and getting this error message when try to calling function of static method dont know why; please do help will be really appericiatable ..

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM' in D:\wamp\www\activecollab\public\activecollab\3.0.9\modules\projectcomrequest\models\Projectcomrequests.class.php on line 130
```

the code I did in model file is:

```
  class Projectrequests extends DataManager {

   ...
   ....

        function getPermissionValue($name){
            $roles = Roles::find();
            foreach($roles as $role) {
                if($role->getPermissionValue($name))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }

        static function canAccess() {
          if(self::getPermissionValue('can_use_project_request')) return true;
            return false;
        } // canAccess

  ...
  ..

  }
```

calling in controller by this:

```
echo Projectrequests::canAccess();
```

Comment: I see you're using `$this` inside the static function `canAccess()`, which is not permissible, but shouldn't cause that particular error

Comment: Perfect example of why curly-braces should never be omitted for control structures. You're not being clever or tidy by leaving them out. [Voted to close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87149/should-syntax-error-questions-be-closed-as-too-localized-after-being-answered). [Or maybe a dupe?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parse+error%3A+parse+error%2C+expecting+%60T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM%27)

Comment: I disagree, it's a better example of why you should have curly braces on the next line, instead of at the end of a line.

Comment: @SLC Where do see a trailing closing curly brace in his code? All of his `}` are on their own line or silently-implied (which was the focus of my point)

Comment: @Mike if you see his `foreach(...) {` has the `{` on the same line. If he put it onto a newline it would be more obvious there was a missing `}` because they wouldn't line up vertically.

Comment: @SLC [To each his own](http://i.imgur.com/xs8kz.png). The last one is the most-obvious to me b/c the last line isn't indented back to the gutter like it should be. It's worse (imho) in the first two because of the explicit indent of the braceless if condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        if($role->getPermissionValue($name))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

You're missing a closing } there.  So it should be:

```
  class Projectrequests extends DataManager {

   ...
   ....

        function getPermissionValue($name){
            $roles = Roles::find();
            foreach($roles as $role) {
                if($role->getPermissionValue($name))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            } // <-- here
        }

        static function canAccess() {
          if(self::getPermissionValue('can_use_project_request')) return true;
            return false;
        } // canAccess

  ...
  ..

  }
```

Comment: That foreach is kind of useless since it now only loops once.

Comment: Not looking further than the stated is not always the best approach to answer and help a person.

Comment: Does it resolve the error as asked by the OP? :)  I think yes.

Comment: As a matter of fact, no it doesn't. It introduces other errors (like that "only loop once in foreach").

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't introduce that at all.  How does my fix (of one closing brace) introduce a bug where the foreach only goes round once?  That would -always- happen given this code.  It's not _introduced_, it was in the original code.  Granted, the original code has faaaar more errors than just a missing bracket, but that bracket was causing the given error in the original post.  Therefore that is what I answered.  End of story.

Comment: @Styxxy yes no need to add `else` condition .. but the thing is that this value `if($role->getPermissionValue($name))` is present in `foreach` everytime .. so I just want to check its position if it is on first then it is true else must return false .. so that's why i need it .. and I can do this without `foreach` too by using array with first index.

Answer (score 3):

A static method doesn't have a class context `$this` as you try to call in the first line of `canAccess()`. You should call `self::` instead of `$this->` to access the class context and then you can only call other static field and methods. You will have to make `getPermissionValue` also static.

A few more errors:

- You forgot a `{` in your foreach. Fixed this for you (only return true inside the loop, the else construction is useless because otherwise your foreach only loops once).
- You can immediately return the value of the call to `getPermissionValue` in `canAccess` since it is a boolean anyway (the if-else construction is kind of useless).

Corrected code:

```
static function getPermissionValue($name){
    $roles = Roles::find();
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        if($role->getPermissionValue($name))
            return true;
    }    
    return false;
}

static function canAccess() {
    return self::getPermissionValue('can_use_project_request');
} // canAccess
```

I would like to advice as well to use access modifiers like `public` and `private` as it is good practice.

Comment: `public` and `private` are not required. When omitted from method declaration, `public` will be used. Marking methods as `static` on the other hand is encouraged, because PHP raises warning (or notice, can't remember) when method that's not marked as static is called statically.

Comment: True it is not required, but it is in my opinion good practice to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
class Projectrequests extends DataManager {

   ...
   ....

        function getPermissionValue($name){
            $roles = Roles::find();
            foreach($roles as $role) {
                if($role->getPermissionValue($name))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            } // <!---- YOUR ERROR IS HERE
        }

        static function canAccess() {
          if($this->getPermissionValue('can_use_project_request')) return true;
            return false;
        } // canAccess

  ...
  ..

  }
```

Also, static methods do not have access to `$this` you need to use `self::` instead